# Java - basic hardcoded user input login screen

Tags: java, methods, authentication, boolean

I am trying to make a basic login screen for my practice application. At the moment I got this class in the main class:

```
        private static boolean inlogMenu(Scanner sc){
            System.out.println(" -- Inloggen ZVC Volkel --");
            for(int i = 1; i <= 3;  i++) {
                System.out.println("Gebruikersnaam?");
                String gebnaam = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Wachtwoord?");
                String wachtwoord = sc.nextLine();

                for(Lid inloglid : zvcvolkel.getLeden()){
                    if(gebnaam.equals(inloglid.getGebnaam()) && inloglid.checkWachtwoord(wachtwoord)){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Inloggegevens ongeldig");
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I tried adding different println to see what's going wrong. It adds the user input to the String, but the problem lays in the second for loop. It should loop through a ArrayList (zvcvolkel.getLeden()) but it just completely skips it and goes straight to the Inloggegevens ongeldig println.

Anyone knows what's wrong?

Comment: Have you checked if list that you return with getLeden actually contains input username and password?

Comment: Yes it does, I tried adding a println in the loop and it doesnt print out anything. There are records in the ArrayList.

Comment: Well can't help much with code you provided, my suggestion is to use debugger, if you haven't used it before then this looks like great chance to learn it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call a variable from outside your method. This creates all kinds of problems. Pass it to the method as parameter and use it locally. This way you can store the list in an array inside the method and debug it from there.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it like you and @FilipRistic told me to and now it works like a charm! Cheers!

Comment: In that case you should accept this as an answer to your question.